# In OpenLayers, why is useInterimTilesOnError behavior different on translated MVT layers?

Tags: openlayers

When rendering a translated MVT layer, if `useInterimTilesOnError` is true, portions of some tiles are not rendered. However, the full tiles are rendered if either (1) the layer is untranslated or (2) the layer is translated but `useInterimTilesOnError` is false.

If you run this example, the third map shows these half-rendered tiles:

```js
var proj3857 = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857');

var center = ol.proj.fromLonLat([133.9789237, -23.6188074]);
var view = new ol.View({
  center: center,
  maxZoom: 23,
  zoom: 10,
  projection: proj3857
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  opacity: .4,
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    maxZoom: 23,
  })
});
createMap('untranslated', 0, true);
createMap('false', 20000, false);
createMap('true', 20000, true);

function createMap(id, dx, useInterimTilesOnError) {

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster],
    target: id,
    view: view
  });

  let dy = 0;
  var extent = proj3857.getExtent();
  var offsetExtent = [extent[0] + dx, extent[1] + dy, extent[2] + dx, extent[3] + dy];

  var layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
      format: new ol.format.MVT(),
      wrapX: false,
      url: 'https://basemaps.arcgis.com/v1/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf',
      tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
        extent: offsetExtent,
        maxZoom: 18
      })
    }),
    useInterimTilesOnError: useInterimTilesOnError,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        width: 1,
        color: 'black'
      })
    })
  });

  map.addLayer(layer);

  map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileDebug({
      projection: proj3857,
      tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
        extent: offsetExtent,
        maxZoom: 18
      })
    })
  }));
}
```

```css
.map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div>
  <h4>Untranslated plus useInterimTilesOnError: true</h4>
  <div id="untranslated" class="map"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Translated plus useInterimTilesOnError: false</h4>
  <div id="false" class="map"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Translated plus useInterimTilesOnError: true</h4>
  <div id="true" class="map"></div>
</div>
```

If there is a problem with a tile, I would expect it to be drawn improperly in the first, untranslated map as well.

[ As an aside... I also expected that `useInterimTilesOnError` applied only to tiles that could not be retrieved. But, clearly these tiles are being retrieved. I'm not sure what other kind of error might be going on with them? ]

Answer (score 1):

With `useInterimTilesOnError: true` there seems to be an issue because the view projection extent doesn't match the tilegrid extent, and tiles are being cropped based the view projection.  Vector tiles cannot be reprojected so having the same projection but different extents seems to be the cause.  Definining a translated extent and using it for the view seems to fix it, and the raster layer can be "reprojected" (although as the only differences between the coordinates will be close to the date line there is unlikely to be much overhead involved).

I've added some more scenarios to your demo:

```js
var proj3857 = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857');

proj4.defs('EPSG:3857X', '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs');

if (ol.proj.proj4 && ol.proj.proj4.register) { ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4); }

var dx = 20000;
var dy = 0;

var extent = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857').getExtent();
var offsetExtent = [extent[0] + dx, extent[1] + dy, extent[2] + dx, extent[3] + dy];

var proj3857X = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857X');
proj3857X.setGlobal(true);
proj3857X.setExtent(offsetExtent);

var center = ol.proj.fromLonLat([133.9789237, -23.6188074]);
var view = new ol.View({
  center: center,
  maxZoom: 23,
  zoom: 10,
  projection: proj3857
});

var viewX = new ol.View({
  center: center,
  maxZoom: 23,
  zoom: 10,
  projection: proj3857X
});

  var sync = true;

  view.on(['change:center','change:resolution','change:rotation'], function() {
    if (sync) {
      var center = view.getCenter();
      var zoom = view.getZoom();
      var rotation = view.getRotation();
      sync = false;
      viewX.animate({
        center: center,
        zoom: zoom,
        rotation: rotation,
        duration: 0
      }, function() { sync = true; });
    }
  });

 viewX.on(['change:center','change:resolution','change:rotation'], function() {
    if (sync) {
      var center = viewX.getCenter();
      var zoom = viewX.getZoom();
      var rotation = viewX.getRotation();
      sync = false;
      view.animate({
        center: center,
        zoom: zoom,
        rotation: rotation,
        duration: 0
      }, function() { sync = true; });
    }
  });

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  opacity: .4,
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    maxZoom: 23,
  })
});
createMap('untranslated-false', 0, 0, false, view);
createMap('untranslated-true', 0, 0, true, view);
createMap('false', dx, dy, false, view);
createMap('true', dx, dy, true, view);
createMap('projected-false', dx, dy, false, viewX);
createMap('projected-true', dx, dy, true, viewX);

function createMap(id, dx, dy, useInterimTilesOnError, view) {

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster],
    target: id,
    view: view
  });

  var extent = proj3857.getExtent();
  var offsetExtent = [extent[0] + dx, extent[1] + dy, extent[2] + dx, extent[3] + dy];

  var layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
      format: new ol.format.MVT(),
      //wrapX: false,
      projection: view.getProjection(),
      url: 'https://basemaps.arcgis.com/v1/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf',
      tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
        extent: offsetExtent,
        maxZoom: 18
      })
    }),
    useInterimTilesOnError: useInterimTilesOnError,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        width: 1,
        color: 'black'
      })
    })
  });

  map.addLayer(layer);

  map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileDebug({
      projection: proj3857,
      tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
        extent: offsetExtent,
        maxZoom: 18
      })
    })
  }));
}
```

```css
.map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>
<div>
  <h4>Untranslated plus useInterimTilesOnError: false</h4>
  <div id="untranslated-false" class="map"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Untranslated plus useInterimTilesOnError: true</h4>
  <div id="untranslated-true" class="map"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Translated plus useInterimTilesOnError: false</h4>
  <div id="false" class="map"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Translated plus useInterimTilesOnError: true</h4>
  <div id="true" class="map"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Projected plus useInterimTilesOnError: false</h4>
  <div id="projected-false" class="map"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Projected plus useInterimTilesOnError: true</h4>
  <div id="projected-true" class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The map I'm developing may have multiple MVT layers, each needing to be translated by a different amount. So it really is the *layer* that needs to be translated; a workaround won't suffice.